# n! mod p Fast Factorial

Tags: mathematical-programming

I need to find **N! (mod 2<sup>32</sup>-5)** such that **0 ≤ N ≤ 2<sup>64</sup>** for **i** cases, **0 ≤ i ≤ 1000** in 1 sec.

Credits: https://dmoj.ca/problem/factorial2

I am aware that I only have to handle **0 ≤ N ≤ 2 ≤ 2<sup>32</sup>-6** because once **N ≥ 2<sup>32</sup>-5**, **N!≡0 (mod 2<sup>32</sup>-5)** . A naive solution would take **O((2<sup>32</sup>-6)*1000)**. I have also tried using Wilson’s Theorem and a naive solution, which would run in approximately **O(4000000000*1000)** time (Calculated from the highest point when **O(N)** intersects with **O(2<sup>32</sup>-5-N)log(N))**).

I cannot find a solution to this problem with a fast enough run time.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, $2^{32}-5$ is prime. According to [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8f10/92abf31d6f39cc56c0a027ea183f11b3eb7f.pdf), computing $n!\mod m$ is as hard as factoring $m$. So you should probably look for algorithm that use the primality of $2^{32}-5$.

Comment: Try sorting your inputs, and so save a factor of $i$.

Comment: Yuval's advice, plus a massive amount of brute force on a decent computer, should just about do the job on a decent home computer with say 4 cores, and a good vector unit.

Comment: Using a table of size M containing strategically precomputed values of $n! \bmod{2^{32}-5}$, you can save a factor of M in the computation time, though then you can't use my previous optimization.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-n-under-modulo-p/

Comment: @YuvalFilmus unfortunately, there is a character limit for the grader. I would require a precomputed number every 30000 numbers in order to not go over the time limit.

Comment: @Eugene I have looked at the website and have tried using their method. The second attempt using Wilson's theorem was still too slow as I needed to use part of the naive solution since Wilson's theorem would take too long for smaller numbers.

Answer (score 1):

First use Yuval's advice: With p = 2^32 - 5, remove all N ≥ p (the result is 0), then sort the rest, so now you have up to 1,000 numbers in sorted order from 0 to p-1. This is trivial to do by multiplying up to almost 2^32 numbers modulo p and recording results at the right moment; that's not *much* above a second worth of work but more than a second.

Let's say you have r processors, and you want to use them simultaneously. The largest number is t < p. You make each processor responsible for multiplying s = ceil (t / r) numbers. For example if r = 8 and t = 2^32 - 6, then s = 2^29. Processor 0 multiplies numbers from 1 to s, processor 1 multiplies numbers from s+1 to 2s and so on. Let's say one of your N's is 3s + 15900: Processor 3 multiplies 3s+1 to 4s. At some point you record the product of numbers 3s+1 to 3s+15,900. And when all the processors are done, you multiply with the final results of processors 0, 1 and 2.

You may have vector units being able to do for example 4 operations in parallel. In that case, you would multiply r by 4, and have 8 processors calculating 4 results simultaneously.

Say you have calculated x (x+1) modulo p, the product of two numbers. How can you get (x+2)(x+3) modulo p, the next product? (x+2)(x+3)-x(x+1) = 4x + 6, so the product modulo p changes by (4x + 6) modulo p. Let d(x) = (4x + 6) modulo p. As you increase x by 2, d(x) changes by 8 (modulo p), so the products x(x+1) modulo p, (x+2)(x+3) modulo p, (x+4)(x+5) modulo p etc. can be calculated very quickly. I think that should be enough to get you below one second.

Some additions: One, **if p** = $2^{32}-5$ **is not prime**, **that makes the problem just faster to solve**. If all prime factors are ≤ $p^{1/2}$ then the problem is trivial because N! = 0 (modulo p) if N ≥ $2^{17}$ (must be careful in case p is the square of a prime). Otherwise let p = a·q, where a ≥ 2 and q is a prime q ≥ $p^{1/2}$, then we can calculate N! modulo p easily from N! modulo a and N! modulo q. Since $a ≤ 2^{16}$ and N! modulo a = 0 if N ≥ a, calculating N! modulo a is trivial (only 65535 products needed). b would be at most half as large as p, making the problem at least twice as fast to solve. After applying this, we can assume p is prime.

Two, **Wilson's Theorem lets you cut the time in half**. We now assume p is prime (having cut down the time earlier if the original p wasn't). Wilson's Theorem says (p-1)! = -1 (modulo p). Now say we want to calculate (p-k)! modulo p. We have obviously (p-k)! · ((p-k+1)·(p-k+2)· ... · (p-1)) = (p-1)!. This product is equal to (p-k)! · (-(k-1))·(-(k-2))· ... · (-1)) = (p-k)! · (k-1)! · (-1)^(k-1). The result modulo p is -1, so (p-k)!·(k-1)! = (-1)^k modulo p. So if p/2 ≤ N < p, then we let k = p - N, calculate (k-1)! modulo p, and solve N! · (k-1)! = (-1)^k modulo p. The problem is now mostly reduced to the problem of calculating N! modulo p for about 1,000 values 0 ≤ N ≤ p/2 ≤ $2^{31}$.

Three, **Yuval's idea** using a table with pre-calculated values N! modulo p will work if the task is to solve the problem for fixed p and different sets of 1,000 values N. If there are 1,000 values N you need **1,000k precalculated values to save a factor k**. It doesn't work if p is variable. 
And if it is possible to use multiple processors or vector units to do k calculations in parallel, then a factor k in time can be saved. Without these savings, it's 2 billion products modulo p in 1 second.

One idea is factoring N! into a product of powers primes. There are less than 100 million primes < $2^{31}$. However, since we have 1,000 values $N < 2^{31}$, I think many primes will have to be multiplied multiple times. Doing this in one second is tough.

Comment: I'm not sure you're allowed to use several processors. The program runs on an online judge.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I am using an online grader

Comment: Unfortunately **2^32 -5**  is prime and Wilson's Theorem only has a run time of **O(2^32-5-N)log(N)))** as I mentioned in my question. Also N has 2^32-6 possible values and would take 16GB to store so that's out of the question

Comment: @WIR3D: What are you going on about there? I wrote a very simple method where (p-k)! modulo p is easily calculated from k! modulo p, which means you don't need to calculat N! modulo p for any N > p/2. "Wilson's Theorem" doesn't have a runtime, it's something you use. And it doesn't need any storage.